# Revert to .psd from .pdf

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf

I saved my `.psd` file as `.pdf` to - well - see a pdf version of it. I think I might have unchecked the thing that keeps it editable and keeps the layers.

Is this revertable? Can I get my psd file back?

I kept working on the `.psd` file but it's nowhere to be found.

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you sure your *.psd is gone? If you used 'save as', your original file should still be around. Have a peek at the recent files?

Comment: Illustrator might be better at recovering anything that's recoverable. Do you have that available?

Comment: if you opened the psd file and hit "save as" then the psd file should still be there somewhere unless you deleted it manually.

Answer (score 4):

Saving an existing .psd as a PDF will customarily generate a **new and separate file** for the PDF. It doesn't overwrite any existing .psd file on your system. So, if you were working from an existing file the .psd should still be present on your hard drive. If you started a file from scratch, saved it as a pdf... then.....

**If the file is still open**, Choose `File > Save As` and save it as a PSD again.

**If you've closed the file**, and the *Preserve Photoshop Edit Capabilities* was indeed unchecked, the best you can do is reopen the PDF with Photoshop and see what was retained. You may get lucky and still have some parts. Most likely there are areas where flattening occurred and you can't simply revert from a file which has been closed. Often Photoshop will simply rasterize the entire PDF if editing was not preserved.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot find the psd file, check out the largest sized pdf file with the same name in the folder you saved in and open in photoshop. It might contain the editable layers.

Answer (score 0):

If you mistakenly saved the file as pdf but wanted to save the file as PSD and you close the file from photoshop 7.0. Relax nothing to worry about this. Open this mistakenly saved pdf file again in photoshop 7.00 you will get your all layers back there now you can save the file as PSD. :)